# Can I remove the begin end statements if using a try catch block

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft Sql I have the following code snippet of a much larger stored procedure.

```
if @ErrorValue = 0
begin
    begin try   
        INSERT INTO MyItems (GroupID, OrderID, MajorNum)
        VALUES              (@GroupID, @OrderID,@MajorNum)      
        SELECT  @RecordsAffected = @@RowCount, @ErrorValue = @@Error
        if @GroupID is null
            set @ResultMessage = 'New In Cell Record'
        else
            set @ResultMessage = 'New GroupID:' +  convert(varchar,@GroupID)
    end try
    begin catch
        set @ResultMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE ()
        set @ErrorValue = ERROR_NUMBER()
    end catch
end
else
begin
   ...
end
```

In keeping the lines of code down I experemented with removing the begin and end from the first block as I was using a try catch. It works like the first version.
Is there any problem with doing this?

```
if @ErrorValue = 0
    begin try   
        INSERT INTO MyItems (GroupID, OrderID, MajorNum)
        VALUES              (@GroupID, @OrderID,@MajorNum)      
        SELECT  @RecordsAffected = @@RowCount, @ErrorValue = @@Error
        if @GroupID is null
            set @ResultMessage = 'New In Cell Record'
        else
            set @ResultMessage = 'New GroupID:' +  convert(varchar,@GroupID)
    end try
    begin catch
        set @ResultMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE ()
        set @ErrorValue = ERROR_NUMBER()
    end catch
else
    begin
        ...
    end
```

Thanks.

Comment: If your actual code has a try/catch block in the `ELSE` block with an identical catch, I suggest an outer try/catch instead. That would avoid duplicating the catch block.

Comment: It doesn't but has elsewhere in the code. So I was planning to do that. I am more interested if the begin try, end try, begin catch, end catch will be handled as a single entity (for want of a bertter word) and don't need to be surrounded by a begin, end because of this.

Answer (score 0):

The BEGIN in the first block is for the IF statement. If you don't have a BEGIN in IF block, only the first statement following IF will be executed inside IF block. Next set of statements will execute outside IF. Since

```
BEGIN TRY
... 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
...
END CATCH
```

is inside IF and is considered as one BLOCK, you didn't see any difference in execution

Comment: I understand that the begin and end is for the if statement. What I was wondering was if that was redundant. Given that the begin try, end try, begin catch, end catch are a block in their own right. I'm lead to believe this as Microsift comments 'A TRY block must be immediately followed by an associated CATCH block' and 'If there are no errors in the code that is enclosed in a TRY block, when the last statement in the TRY block has finished running, control passes to the statement immediately after the associated END CATCH statement.

Comment: if I get an error in the 2nd code snippet it does run the code inbetween the BEGIN CATCH and END CATCH. Which if I understand you comment correctly you thought that ' only the first statement following IF will be executed inside IF block'